# Modify vim-fugitive Gstatus mapping

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

The `:Gstatus` window has specific mappings for that particular buffer. In my case, I would like to change the `cc` mapping to not only execute `:Gcommit` but also go into insert mode afterwards.

It seems like the user `robodendron` figured out how to do this as shown in https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/647, but I'm don't know what he means when he says "changing the order should be enough." Also, I would ask this on the Git issues page, but it seems like the user `NicolasWebDev` already tried that and no one got back to him.

I can add mappings by creating a `after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim` file, but modifying an existing mapping seems to be more difficult since the mapping is defined after the filetype is set.

Also, I could modify the source code mappings, but we all know that's more of a temporary fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about trying to alter `:Gstatus` mappings, but you can start insert mode when entering the commit buffer.

Add the following to your `vimrc` file:

```
augroup turbo_commit
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter COMMIT_EDITMSG startinsert
augroup END
```

For more help see:

```
:h :autocmd
:h :augroup
:h BufEnter
:h startinsert
```